# Trigger CSV import

Tags: magento2, import

I'm looking for automating product imports from CSV into magento2.

Is there a way to trigger such an import? I could not find anything in the REST documentation.

I know there are ways to schedule a cron job like import,
but I would like to trigger the import explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is free extension which provide CLI commands for Magento 2 import functionality https://github.com/cedricblondeau/magento2-module-catalog-import-command even that is seems like out of date and have few issues, maybe it can be helpful as starting point.